# Como guardar a posição do vídeo do Jwplayer em um cookie

Tags: javascript, html

Ola gostaria de saber como posso alterar o código abaixo que mostra a posição de tempo em que o vídeo se encontra em tempo real. Gostaria que essa posição fosse armazenada em um cookie, com validade, de forma que caso a pagina seja atualizada, o cookie seja acionado, colocando o vídeo na posição em que o vídeo parou.

Código

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size:1em;
        line-height:1.8em;
    }
    h2,#timer {
        background-color:#000;
        color:#0f0;
        font-size:2em;
        margin:0em;
        width:200px;
        height:1.2em;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://osric.com/chris/javascript/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://osric.com/chris/jwplayer/jwplayer5.4/jwplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        file:"url do vídeo aqui",
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
            events: {
            onTime: function(event) {
                $('#timer').html(Math.floor(event.position));
            }
        }
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>



<div id="container"></div>

<h2>Timer:</h2>
<div id="timer"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual seria a validade? Em horas, dias, minutos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponho que você já tenha separado o tempo de um player, o que você está tentando fazer é um trabalho um pouco complicado, eu vou te dar uma base para montar a sua lógica, tem duas formas de fazer isso, uma é com [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) e a outra é com [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Primeira mente para guardar um cookie, você pode usar o javascript puro e escrever algo assim:

```
//javascript
document.cookie = "tempo=123";
```

Todo cookie fica armazenado dentro do `document.cookie`, mas isso não vai durar por muito tempo, por isso você pode definir um tempo, algo do tipo:

```
//javascript
document.cookie = "tempo=123; expires=Wed, 23 Dec 2020 12:00:00 UTC";
```

Esse cookie vai ficar em "pé" até 23 de dezembro, e para puxar essa data você pode receber dessa forma:

```
//javascript
ver cookie = document.cookie;
```

O problema é que ele vai retornar uma string loga com todo o texto armazenado, por isso você pode utilizar uma API muito comum que é a [CookieJs](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), é bem mais simples de trabalhar com ela, e seu código ficaria algo assim:

```
//CookiesJS API
Cookies.set('tempo', '123456', { expires: 7 });
var cookie = Cookies.get('tempo');
```

E para finalizar quando carregar é preciso pegar o elemento video e alterar o tempo, o primeiro passo é ter certeza que ele foi carregado antes do script para alterar o tempo, pois o javascript é assíncrono e isso pode dar um pouco de dor de cabeça, entretanto para alterar o tempo é assim;

```
//javascript
var player = document.getElementById('container').children;

for (var i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {

    if (player[i].nodeName == "VIDEO") {

        player[i].currentTime = 123;

        break;

    }

}
```

**NOTA:** O Jwplayer pode ocorrer erro não planejados ao alterar o tempo, pois toda API sempre tem falhas que não foram planejadas, mas acredito que isso não vai te atrapalhar.